# Complex mySQL Query (again)

Tags: mysql

My apologies that the question title is not more specific.

I am working on a system that involves stock control and membership records.  The current problem relates to the 'membership packs' that are given to new members on joining; there are a variety of membership types and each one gets a pack with several items in, no two packs are exactly the same but there is some overlap with some products being used in more than one pack. I need to calculate the number of each product that is used in a given batch of new members.

I can create a query that gives me the total of different membership types in a batch.

I can create a query that give me the total of each product required to make one of each of those packs.

I need to create a query that is a combination of both.

The query that gives the total of each type in a batch:

    `SELECT COUNT(*) AS theCount, membershipPackType
    FROM inputBatches
    LEFT JOIN inputActions ON inputActionID = inputBatchAction
    LEFT JOIN members ON memberID = inputBatchMemberID
    LEFT JOIN membershipPacks ON membershipPackType = memberMembershipType
    LEFT JOIN memPack ON memPackInputBatch = inputBatchID
    WHERE memPackBookedOut = 'U' 
    AND inputActionAbbr <> 'E'
    GROUP BY membershipPackType
    ORDER BY membershipPackType;`

This query produces the output at the top of the linked image:

The query that gives the total of each product to make one of each of the types from the result of the above query:

    `SELECT COUNT(*) AS theCount, stockItem 
    FROM membershipPackItems 
    LEFT JOIN membershipPacks ON membershipPackNumber = membershipPackType 
    LEFT JOIN stock ON stockNumber = membershipPackItemNo 
    WHERE membershipPackNumber = 11 OR membershipPackNumber = 12 OR membershipPackNumber = 13 OR membershipPackNumber = 14 OR membershipPackNumber = 23 OR membershipPackNumber = 24   OR membershipPackNumber = 25
    GROUP BY stockItem 
    ORDER BY stockNumber;`

This query produces the output at the bottom of this image:

http://www.kidderminsterharriers.com/images/query4.png

If I could combine the two queries then I wouldn't have the WHERE clause in the second query that is hard-coded like that. Also, what this second query doesn't allow for is that the membershipPackItems table includes a field for quantity; it assumes that the quantity of each item per pack is 1.

The ultimate aim is to have query that outputs in a similar fashion to the second query but that the column that is currently 'theCount' is a total allows for the number of each item in the pack (ie more than 1 if needed) and then multiplied up by the number of packs in the batch; in this case those items that currently have a count of 7 (there's 7 different types in this batch and those items appear in all of them) would be 62 (there's 62 members total in this batch).

This is the structure of the data tables used:

`CREATE TABLE membershipPackItems (
  membershipPackItemID int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  membershipPackNumber int(7) NOT NULL,
  membershipPackItemNo varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  membershipPackItemQty int(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (membershipPackItemID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=71 ;`

CREATE TABLE `membershipPacks` (
  `membershipPackID` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `membershipPackTitle` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `membershipPackType` int(5) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`membershipPackID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `stockID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `stockNumber` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `stockItem` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `stockNominalNo` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockVATNo` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `stockDecLevel` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `stockPeriodSold` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockPeriodSoldValue` float NOT NULL,
  `stockPPurchased` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockYTDSold` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockYTDSoldValue` float NOT NULL,
  `stockYTDPurchased` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockDefectLevel` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockCurrentLevel` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockReOrderLevel` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockHolding` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockBackOrderQty` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockRetail` float NOT NULL,
  `stockCost` float NOT NULL,
  `stockOrdered` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockSupplierNo` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `stockSupplierStockNo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `stockDeliveryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `stockDeleted` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `stockAllowedLeaps` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `stockCount` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `stockCountDate` date NOT NULL,
  `stockCountComment` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `stockGroup1` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `stockGroup2` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `stockNewStockNo` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `stockStatus` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`stockID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1779 ;

CREATE TABLE `inputBatches` (
  `inputBatchID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `inputBatchInputNumber` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `inputBatchMemberID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `inputBatchAction` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `inputBatchDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`inputBatchID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=88 ;

CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `memberID` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `memberCentre` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `memberMembershipNo` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `memberSurname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberForename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberSecondName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberParentTitle` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `memberParentSurname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberParentForename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberStreet1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `memberStreet2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `memberTown` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberCounty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `memberPostcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `memberPhoneSTD` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `memberPhone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `memberMobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `memberEmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `memberDOB` date NOT NULL,
  `memberJoined` date NOT NULL,
  `memberGender` enum('m','f') NOT NULL,
  `memberSibling` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `memberMembershipType` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `memberSpecNeedsNo` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `memberPromoNo` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `memberDataProtect` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `memberReceived` date NOT NULL,
  `memberMemberType` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `memberSendPack` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `memberSendGift` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `memberExpire` date NOT NULL,
  `memberDespatched` date NOT NULL,
  `memberInputNo` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `memberSSC` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `memberPrevStreet1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `memberPrevStreet2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `memberPrevTown` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `memberPrevCounty` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `memberPrevPostcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `memberPrevCentre` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `memberInvoiced` float NOT NULL,
  `memberPaid` float NOT NULL,
  `memberSpecNeedsString` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `memberNotes` mediumtext,
  `memberMembershipYear` int(3) default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`memberID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `memberMembershipNo` (`memberMembershipNo`),
  KEY `memberFullName` (`memberSurname`,`memberForename`),
  KEY `memberSurname` (`memberSurname`),
  KEY `memberForename` (`memberForename`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=631747 ;

CREATE TABLE `memPack` (
  `memPackID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `memPackBookedOut` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `memPackDate` date NOT NULL,
  `memPackMembershipNo` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `memPackLicenseeNo` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `memPackMemTypeNo` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `memPackInputNumber` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `memPackInputBatch` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `memPackCentreNo` int(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`memPackID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13675 ;

Comment: Could have been easier to trace the relationships of the columns if foreign keys were used.

Answer (score 0):

**You can combine both queries by joining them on membershipPackType.**

The `INNER JOIN` with your first query takes care of the hardcoded `WHERE` clause.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS theCount
        , stockItem 
FROM    membershipPackItems 
        LEFT JOIN membershipPacks ON membershipPackNumber = membershipPackType 
        LEFT JOIN stock ON stockNumber = membershipPackItemNo 
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  COUNT(*) AS theCount
                  , membershipPackType
          FROM    inputBatches
                  LEFT JOIN inputActions ON inputActionID = inputBatchAction
                  LEFT JOIN members ON memberID = inputBatchMemberID
                  LEFT JOIN membershipPacks ON membershipPackType = memberMembershipType
                  LEFT JOIN memPack ON memPackInputBatch = inputBatchID
          WHERE   memPackBookedOut = 'U' 
                  AND inputActionAbbr <> 'E'
          GROUP BY 
                  membershipPackType
        ) cnt ON cnt.membershipPackType = membershipPackItems.membershipPackType
GROUP BY stockItem 
ORDER BY stockNumber;
```

### Edit

I have trimmed down the scripts and altered your first query as below in an effort to try and understand what is what.

If you provide some scripts to fill the tables with some data (preferably the data that should become the outputs you've posted), I am willing to have another look at it, otherwise, this is as far as I am prepared to go with this, sorry.

*Note: that you should definitly strive for a consistent naming scheme. membershipPackItemNo in one table is stockNumber in an other, Packtype links with PackNumber, memPackInputBatch links with inputBatchID. If not for your own sanity, it would make it much easier for us to figure out what is what.*

*Note: the scripts have been changed for SQL Server. I don't have a MySQL running.*

```
CREATE TABLE membershipPackItems (
  membershipPackNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  membershipPackItemNo varchar(6) NOT NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE membershipPacks (
  membershipPackType INTEGER default NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE stock (
  stockNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  stockItem varchar(50) NOT NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE inputBatches (
  inputBatchID INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  inputBatchMemberID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  inputBatchAction INTEGER NOT NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE members (
  memberID INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  memberMembershipType INTEGER NOT NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE memPack (
  memPackBookedOut varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  memPackInputBatch INTEGER NOT NULL,
) 

SELECT  COUNT(*) AS theCount, st.stockItem 
FROM    stock st
        LEFT OUTER JOIN membershipPackItems mpi ON mpi.membershipPackItemNo = st.stockNumber
        LEFT OUTER JOIN membershipPacks mp ON mp.membershipPackType = mpi.membershipPackNumber
WHERE   mpi.membershipPackNumber = 11
GROUP BY stockItem
```

Comment: That combines the two queries nicely but the output is the same as my original second query, it's only giving me the quantity of each stock item required for one of each of the different membership packs.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean but you could add MIN(theCount) from the inner query to the result. If that is not the result you are after, please post the result you want (it's to much for my poor brain).

Comment: If you look at the image that I linked to, the top result shows counts for seven different membership pack types, and these counts add up to 62.

The result that I want will show the total number of each stock item needed to make up those 62 packs.  The result that I have shows me the number of each stock item needed to make one of each of the seven different types.

The desired result would look like this:
http://www.kidderminsterharriers.com/images/query5.png

Comment: Still not sure what you need. It looks like you are trying to output two (loosely) unrelated resultsets as one? Wouldn't it be possible to take the output from two queries and union them together? If you like to peruse this further, could you post the table scripts and data that make up your results?

Comment: I've added the data structure if it helps.
The membershipPackItems table lists the stock items that go into each membership pack.
The stock table is the stock record for each item.
The inputBatches table is the list of new members or renewals or extensions as they are added.
The members table is the full record for each member.
The memPack table relates to the inputBatches table, the memPackBookedOut field is the status flag where the 'U' that we have in the query is 'Unissued'

The join to inputActions can be removed changing inputActionAbbr <>'E' to inputBatchAction <>'2' in the query

Answer (score 0):

LOL **PSEUDOCODE**

> 1. Get the StockItem, and its quantity associated for each
>    membershipPackType. The ff is just a pseudocode but I am thinking that
>    you can create the actual SQL query to get what I am trying to get at.

```
MembershipPackType_Stock = SELECT membershipPackType, 
                    StockItem,  MembershipPackItemQty 
                    FROM MembershipPackItems
                      LEFT JOIN MembershipPacks ON ...
                      LEFT JOIN stock ON ...
```

> 2. Get the number of members for each MembershipPackType in a Batch. The ff SQL query is directly taken from your post.

```
MembershipPackType_Count =  SELECT COUNT(*) AS MemberCount, membershipPackType
    FROM inputBatches
    LEFT JOIN inputActions ON inputActionID = inputBatchAction
    LEFT JOIN members ON memberID = inputBatchMemberID
    LEFT JOIN membershipPacks ON membershipPackType = memberMembershipType
    LEFT JOIN memPack ON memPackInputBatch = inputBatchID
    WHERE memPackBookedOut = 'U' 
    AND inputActionAbbr <> 'E'
    GROUP BY membershipPackType
    ORDER BY membershipPackType;
```

> 3 Then you can easily join `MembershipPackType_Stock` and `MembershipPackType_Count` to get the total number for each `StockItem`. Once again, the ff is just a pseudocode but I hope that you'll get the idea.

```
SELECT StockItem, SUM( MemberCount * MembershipPackItemQty) 
    FROM MembershipPackType_Stock JOIN MembershipPackType_Count
      ON MembershipPackType = ...
      GROUP BY StockItem
```

I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but if I understand your question correctly, I think this is it.